# How do I find and delete these 447mb of files?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac

[image: How do I find and delete these 447mb of files?]

How do I find and delete these 447mb of files?

Comment: Try removing Garage Band app from your mac.

Answer (score 1):

click Go in the menu bar then click Go To Folder then type /Library/Audio then delete the Apple loops folder.If you want delete the other Garage Band Files.